# What use is find_package() when you need to specify CMAKE_MODULE_PATH?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get a cross-plattform build system working using CMake. Now the software has a few dependencies. I compiled them myself and installed them on my system.

Some example files which got installed:

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/SomeLib/SomeDir/somefile
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/SomeLib/SomeDir/someotherfile
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/SomeLib/somesharedlibrary
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/SomeLib/cmake/FindSomeLib.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/SomeLib/cmake/HelperFile.cmake
```

Now CMake has a `find_package()` which opens a `Find*.cmake` file and searches after the library on the system and defines some variables like `SomeLib_FOUND` etc.

My CMakeLists.txt contains something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/local/lib/SomeLib/cmake/;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
find_package(SomeLib REQUIRED)
```

The first command defines where CMake searches after the `Find*.cmake` and I added the directory of `SomeLib` where the `FindSomeLib.cmake` can be found, so `find_package()` works 
as expected.

But this is kind of weird because one of the reasons why `find_package()` exists is to get away from non-cross-plattform hard coded paths.

How is this usually done? Should I copy the `cmake/` directory of `SomeLib` into my project and set the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` relatively?

Comment: That pattern seems very weird to me. Libraries using CMake are not supposed to expose their 'find' module this way. How did you come up with such a way to find that "SomeLib" ? And which lib is it ?

Comment: Something similar is done in http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for . And it's OGRE.

Comment: The section you link to mentions this: "Since CMake (currently) doesn't ship it, you'll have to ship it within your project." This is what I have done in flvmeta to find LibYAML (see https://github.com/noirotm/flvmeta/tree/master/cmake/modules). The module path points to this directory, inside my project.

Comment: I usually copy FindXXX modules to my project and set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH (if those modules not present in CMake of course), I've also seen this pattern many times in other projects

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Command `find_package` has two modes: `Module` mode and `Config` mode. You are trying to
use `Module` mode when you actually need `Config` mode.

#### Module mode

`Find<package>.cmake` file located **within** your project. Something like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
cmake/FindFoo.cmake
cmake/FindBoo.cmake
```

`CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Foo REQUIRED) # FOO_INCLUDE_DIR, FOO_LIBRARIES
find_package(Boo REQUIRED) # BOO_INCLUDE_DIR, BOO_LIBRARIES

include_directories("${FOO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
include_directories("${BOO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
add_executable(Bar Bar.hpp Bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Bar ${FOO_LIBRARIES} ${BOO_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` has high priority and may be usefull when you need to rewrite standard `Find<package>.cmake` file.

#### Config mode (install)

`<package>Config.cmake` file located **outside** and produced by `install`
command of other project (`Foo` for example).

`foo` library:

```bash
> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Foo)

add_library(foo Foo.hpp Foo.cpp)
install(FILES Foo.hpp DESTINATION include)
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES FooConfig.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo)
```

Simplified version of config file:

```bash
> cat FooConfig.cmake 
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library(FOO_LIBRARY_PATH foo HINTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../")
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FOO_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

By default project installed in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` directory:

```bash
> cmake -H. -B_builds
> cmake --build _builds --target install
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/Foo.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libfoo.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Foo/FooConfig.cmake
```

#### Config mode (use)

Use `find_package(... CONFIG)` to include `FooConfig.cmake` with imported target `foo`:

```bash
> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Boo)

# import library target `foo`
find_package(Foo CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(boo Boo.cpp Boo.hpp)
target_link_libraries(boo foo)
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
> cmake --build _builds
Linking CXX executable Boo
/usr/bin/c++ ... -o Boo /usr/local/lib/libfoo.a
```

Note that imported target is **highly** configurable. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838147/2288008).

**Update**

- [Example](https://github.com/forexample/package-example)

Comment: Your answer is great. However, the example at github is more complex that it can be IMO. In the common case where a subdirectory (module) exports a single artifact, lets say a lib along with the headers, you don't need to generate custom *Config.cmake. As a result the configuration can be cut down significantly. I think I'll make a similar example myself.

Comment: @Dimitris Yes, it can be simplified a little bit. I've updated github example so now it doesn't use `configure_package_config_file`. By the way if you have any other suggestions you can send me pull request.

Comment: @rusio Here is my [example](https://github.com/scumm/foobar). It supports monolithic build (all modules from the root folder) or autonomous builds (each module separately, requires install).

Comment: @Dimitris Okay, now I see. Usually the file that you "optimize away" serve for loading extra stuff like [find_dependency](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html). I think it's a good template to start so I will keep it even it's not used in fact. The rest of the code looks more simplier because you're missing some functionality like version, export for dll, layout with `bin/lib` (try to install executable and run it on windows). And namespaces look very pretty, so I will keep them too :) Also I've added `monolithic` build.

Comment: Each of your examples were very helpful to me.  Thank you both!

Comment: @Dimitris `Yes, it can be simplified a little bit. I've updated github example so now it doesn't use configure_package_config_file` just for your information I'm [back](https://github.com/forexample/package-example/commit/cf2ea1d6a209fb9eca2ab83fdd0ac15fe4d3e807) to using this macro since it has a important module `check_required_components`. It can be used to detect misprints in `find_package`, like `find_package(Foo REQUIRE error string)`. CMake think that `error` and `string` is a components and without `check_required_componets` will just ignore the error.

Comment: @ruslo Thanks for the answer. It helped me clear my confusion. I still have one follow up however, how to understand "By default, `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is empty." on the [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH). How did you figure out that in `Module` mode, the default module search path will be under directory "<CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR>/cmake/"? Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Though, I wish by default Module mode was the fallback to Config mode, not the other way around. If you use find_package(Foo REQUIRED) it searches for a module then config. If you use find_package(Foo [CONFIG|MODULE] REQUIRED), it will only search the one you selected.  See my [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978724/how-can-i-make-find-package-search-with-config-mode-and-fallback-on-module-mode/50983667#50983667)

Answer (score 6):

If you are running `cmake` to generate `SomeLib` yourself (say as part of a superbuild), consider using the [User Package Registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry). This requires no hard-coded paths and is cross-platform. On Windows (including mingw64) it works via the registry. If you examine how the list of installation prefixes is constructed by the `CONFIG` mode of the [find_packages()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package) command, you'll see that the User Package Registry is one of elements.

**Brief how-to**

Associate the targets of `SomeLib` that you need outside of that external project  by adding them to an export set in the `CMakeLists.txt` files where they are created:

```
add_library(thingInSomeLib ...)
install(TARGETS thingInSomeLib Export SomeLib-export DESTINATION lib)
```

Create a `XXXConfig.cmake` file for `SomeLib` in its `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}` and store this location in the User Package Registry by adding two calls to [export()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html?highlight=export) to the `CMakeLists.txt` associated with `SomeLib`:

```
export(EXPORT SomeLib-export NAMESPACE SomeLib:: FILE SomeLibConfig.cmake) # Create SomeLibConfig.cmake
export(PACKAGE SomeLib)                                                    # Store location of SomeLibConfig.cmake
```

Issue your `find_package(SomeLib REQUIRED)` commmand in the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the project that depends on `SomeLib` without the "non-cross-platform hard coded paths" tinkering with the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

**When it might be the right approach**

This approach is probably best suited for situations where you'll never use your software downstream of the build directory (e.g., you're cross-compiling and never install anything on your machine, or you're building the software just to run tests in the build directory), since it creates a link to a .cmake file in your "build" output, which may be temporary.

But if you're never actually installing `SomeLib` in your workflow, calling `EXPORT(PACKAGE <name>)` allows you to avoid the hard-coded path. And, of course, if you are installing `SomeLib`, you probably know your platform, `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, etc, so @user2288008's excellent answer will have you covered.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this usually done? Should I copy the `cmake/` directory of SomeLib into my project and set the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH relatively?

If you don't trust CMake to have that module, then - **yes, do that - sort of:** Copy the `find_SomeLib.cmake` and its dependencies into your `cmake/` directory. That's what I do as a fallback. It's an ugly solution though.

Note that the `FindFoo.cmake` modules are each a sort of a bridge between platform-dependence and platform-independence - they look in various platform-specific places to obtain paths in variables whose names is platform-independent.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally `find_package` is a mechanism to find a library, it's header files, etc. all in 1 convenient method.

As is somewhat implied by the name find_package works best with package managers. Either `system package managers` or `language package managers`.

- system package managers: `APT`, `yum`, etc.
- language package managers: `vcpkg`, `conan`, etc.

`find_package` streamlines using a library from a package manager.

Here is a step by step example using a very popular c++ library (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)

1.) Install the library

```
# Note I'm using APT but it doesn't really matter
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

2.) Find the library in your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(example_project)

add_executable(foobar PRIVATE main.cpp)

# Find your library and link to it.
find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

You should now be good to go. If you are using a `system` package manager.

That's because `find_*` calls in CMake check default system locations.

To see how CMake found your package you can use `--debug-find-pkg`.

`cmake -S . -B build --debug-find-pkg=fmt --fresh`

This will show you all the places CMake is looking for a file called `fmt-config.cmake`.

On my machine it was found here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/fmt/fmt-config.cmake
```

`--debug-find` is a VERY useful tool for figuring out how CMake is looking for things.

#### What about non-system package managers?

There are other ways to describe where packages are located. A very common one is modifying `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

From the documentation

> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is a semicolon-separated list of directories specifying installation prefixes to be searched by the find_package(), find_program(), find_library(), find_file(), and find_path() commands. Each command will add appropriate subdirectories (like bin, lib, or include) as specified in its own documentation. By default CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is empty. It is intended to be set by the project.

Package managers like vcpkg handle this automatically for you. Making it as seamless as if you were using a system package manger.

#### Config vs module searching

Now as your original question alludes to there is some confusion in finding things.

There are 2 main modes for finding things.

- `Module` mode

In this mode, CMake searches for a file called Find<PackageName>.cmake, looking first in the locations listed in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, then among the Find Modules provided by the CMake installation.

- `Config` mode

In this mode, CMake searches for a file called -config.cmake or Config.cmake.

Now as you may notice are above example used `Config` mode.

`Config` mode is generally the desirable solution IF available. Since it's basically requires no work from you. `Module` mode requires a CMake module be written to help you find things.

CMake actually has a few built in `Module` mode helpers.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html#find-modules

Like the FindPython3 module. Here is a tiny example

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}")
```

As shown in this python example, `find_package` is more generically speaking a way to find multiple files that belong together in an easy to consume way.

NOTE:

Because these modules are built in you don't need to modify your CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. They are already provided for you. Of course you can make your own if you need to.

#### Final Notes

I'm hoping my answer is more illuminating than confusing and helped you better understand find_package.

For more details on finding behavior in CMake I recommend Craig Scott's book Professional CMake.

https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to specify the module path per se. CMake ships with its own set of built-in find_package scripts, and their location is in the default CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.

The more normal use case for dependent projects that have been CMakeified would be to use CMake's external_project command and then include the Use[Project].cmake file from the subproject. If you just need the Find[Project].cmake script, copy it out of the subproject and into your own project's source code, and then you won't need to augment the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH in order to find the subproject at the system level.

Comment: `their location is in the default CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` by default `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is empty

Comment: Can confirm @user2288008's comment in 2018. `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is empty on Windows.

Comment: It is a project specific variable, for modules shipping with your project.
"By default it is empty, it is intended to be set by the project."
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html