# CMake find_package not finding Find<package>.cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, catkin

I made and installed the aruco library, which put a Findaruco.cmake file in the /usr/local/lib/cmake directory. In my CMakeLists.txt file I have

```
...
find_package(aruco REQUIRED)
```

and it always returns the standard error

```
By not providing "Findaruco.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "aruco", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "aruco" with any of
the following names:

    arucoConfig.cmake
    aruco-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "aruco" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"aruco_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "aruco"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

I've set the environment variable $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to each of the following, and none work

```
/usr/local  
/usr/local/lib  
/usr/local/lib/cmake
```

The only thing that works is setting the following in CMakeLists

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: CMake documents where it looks for CMake modules: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html So the module path looks more suited to me compared to the prefix path.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting **CMake** variable called `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, not the environment one. Use -D flag during `cmake` invocation:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/lib <path to source or build dir>
```

But AFAIR, CMake should look into `/usr/local` prefix as its default behavior.

Comment: This could be a better way instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746936/cmake-of-what-use-is-find-package-if-you-need-to-specify-cmake-module-path-an