# Installing a CMake library: also ship find modules for the dependencies?

Tags: cmake

My CMake library, `MyLibrary`, has a dependency for `OtherLibrary`, that I import with a **non-standard** `FindOtherLibrary.cmake`.

My library depends on `OtherLibrary` publicly:

```
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PUBLIC OtherLibrary::OtherLibrary)
```

When I install `MyLibrary` (together with `MyLibraryConfig.cmake`), and users want to link against it, they therefore need to import `OtherLibrary`.

Is there a good practice regarding how to distribute `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` along `MyLibrary`?

---

Ideally, one could make things even easier for users of `MyLibrary` by importing `OtherLibrary` automatically from the installed config file `MyLibraryConfig.cmake`, if it contains something like

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(OtherLibrary)
```

and knows where `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` is.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Do not understand your problem. `When I install 'MyLibrary' (together with 'MyLibraryConfig.cmake')` - in that case your config file **already** contains paths to your and other libraries and appropriate relation between them. So when user links with `MyLibrary` target, it automatically links with `OtherLibrary`. No `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` script is needed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're correct, as long as the paths for `OtherLibrary` are hard-coded. However, if `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` defines imported targets, which I prefer, users of `MyLibrary` also must be able to find `OtherLibrary` "on their own".

Comment: If you do not want hardcoded paths, you should provide `FindMyLibrary.cmake` script instead of `MyLibraryConfig.cmake`. For work with your library user needs to ship his(her) project with that script, ... and with every other script you describe in docs (and adjust *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* accordingly). So you may provide `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` alongside with `FindMyLibrary.cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev In this case I have a different opinion: it would defeat the whole point! In my eyes `MyLibraryConfig.cmake` is superior to `FindMyLibrary.cmake` since it is able to set all dependencies following how you compiled the shipped `MyLibrary`, while in `FindMyLIbrary.cmake` this would need to be specified manually. Ideally the developers of `OtherLibrary` would also provide `OtherLibraryConfig.cmake`, but this is not the case, and thus my SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to my question.

In principle, it does what @utopia suggested, but in an automated fashion: the end user of my library does not need to set up (or even know about) `FindOtherLibrary.cmake`. It will be imported automatically by `MyLibraryConfig.cmake`.

To do so, I install `FindOtherLibrary.cmake` along `MyLibraryConfig.cmake`:

```
install(FILES
          /path/to/MyLibraryConfig.cmake
        DESTINATION
          lib/cmake/MyLibrary
        )
install(FILES
          /path/to/FindOtherLibrary.cmake
        DESTINATION
          lib/cmake/MyLibrary/Modules
        )
```

And in `MyLibraryConfig.cmake` I set up how to import it:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Modules/")
find_dependency(OtherLibrary REQUIRED)
```

Note that I set the variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` because it is not possible to specify the location of find modules in `find_package` or `find_dependency` (works only for config mode).

Comment: How did you add those lines (`find_dependency` etc) into the config file? Did you add it manually? Is there a way to add it from the CMakeLists?

Comment: I added it manually. To my knowledge there is no way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

"Transitive" behavior for module-mode `find_package()` is not supported.

In fact, I don't believe it is even possible since it requires modifying downstream CMake module path with information you would not have available to you. That's one of the reasons there is a config-mode `find_package()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746936/cmake-of-what-use-is-find-package-if-you-need-to-specify-cmake-module-path-an/20857070#20857070)).

To be clear, a user of your library, which has a dependency on a FindModule library, has no choice but to know how to get a copy of the FindModule script and add it to their CMake module path. This is typically done through documentation. You as the author of a library that uses the FindModule cannot shortcut that process for the end user in any general way. So, there is no "good practice" for such a process.

Otherwise, good practice is to use FindModules only for non-CMake projects and use Config.cmake for CMake projects. If a dependent CMake library has no Config.cmake, you're out of luck (tell them they need it to support CMake in a Bug/Issue report).