# Where to install FindLib.cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm creating a library (called fmi2) which I intend to install on my local machine (via a package manager) and then link to with a bunch of other libraries.

I'll be providing a Findfmi2.cmake file so that I can call `find_package(fmi2)` from my other libraries, but where should this file be conventionally installed?

Here are some choices I've considered and their problems:

- `/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/Findfmi2.cmake`

  - Advantage:  `find_package(fmi2)` will just work
  - Disadvantage: Only works for one version of cmake
- `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/Findfmi2.cmake`

  - Advantage: Should work for any version of cmake
  - Disadvantage: This is not a default folder.  We would need to add `set(CMAKE_MODULES_PATH /usr/share/cmake/Modules)` and this kills any portability.
- `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Findfmi2.cmake`

  - Advantage: Portable, just need to add `set(CMAKE_MODULES_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)`
  - Disadvantage: Not system-wide.  Need to manually add this file to each library that uses it. This duplicates files in my framework.

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920389/installing-a-cmake-library-also-ship-find-modules-for-the-dependencies) some time ago and would be very interested to hear an answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

You are authoring content in CMake. You don't need a FindModule. That is designed to find external non-CMake outputs.

[This Stackoverflow post from ruslo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746936/cmake-of-what-use-is-find-package-if-you-need-to-specify-cmake-module-path-an) should help you understand the difference between `find_package()` module mode and config mode. It also answers your question about paths for FindModules, i.e. they are copied into your CMake project, not discovered system-wide, unless they are part of the official FindModules bundled with CMake in the "Modules" directory.

Modern CMake documentation now finally contains good examples to create a config mode package: [cmake-packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages)

If you want explicit full examples, though using slightly older syntax for the config.cmake files, ruslo has more on [Github](https://github.com/forexample/package-example).