# How can I use cmake to locate jupyter notebook installation

Tags: cmake, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to use cmake find_package() to locate jupyter_notebook installation?

I tried

```
FIND_PACKAGE(jupyter-notebook REQUIRED)
```

but it errors out with

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "Findjupyter-notebook.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "jupyter-notebook", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "jupyter-notebook"
  with any of the following names:

    jupyter-notebookConfig.cmake
    jupyter-notebook-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "jupyter-notebook" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "jupyter-notebook_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "jupyter-notebook" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

However, it has been installed:

```
apt-cache show jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: `find_package` is usually used to find libraries.  I'm not familiar with jupyter, but is it a library?  If it's an application (my quick googling suggests this), then you actually want `find_program`.

Comment: @Stephen Newell Thanks, I added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options when using the `find_package` command, `MODULE` and `CONFIG`. For this case, you likely want the `CONFIG` setting. The error message is trying to help here. Did either of these files come with the jupyter-notebook installation?

```
jupyter-notebookConfig.cmake
jupyter-notebook-config.cmake
```

If so, try setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `jupyter-notebook_DIR` to the directory where jupyter-notebook was installed. So you might try something like the following:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /path/to/your/installation) # Try this one.
# SET(jupyter-notebook_DIR /path/to/your/installation) # Or try this one.
FIND_PACKAGE(jupyter-notebook CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

If your installation does not appear to have the aforementioned CMake config files, nor does it appear to have any CMake support files (a `cmake` directory, etc.), the [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) command is likely more appropriate for jupyter-notebook.

I suggest spending some time with the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) for `find_package`, as it explicitly lays out the search paths (in order) CMake uses to find your packages. Also, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857070/3987854).