# CMake with 3rd party libraries that need to be built along with the project

Tags: c++, cmake

I am confused on the right way to get an external library integrated into my own Cmake project (This external project needs to be built along with my project, it's not installed separately, so we can't use `find_library`, or so I think)

Let's assume we have a project structure like this (simplified for this post):

```
my_proj/
--CMakeLists.txt
--src/
  +---CMakeLists.txt
  +---my_server.cpp
```

That is, we have a master CMakeLists.txt that basically sits at root and invokes CMakeLists for sub directories. Obviously, in this example, because its simplified, I'm not showing all the other files/directories.

I now want to include another C++ GitHub project in my build, which happens to be this C++ bycrypt implementation: https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt

My goal:

- While building my_server.cpp via its make process, I'd like to include the header files for bcrypt and link with its library.

What I've done so far:
- I added a git module for this external library at my project root:

```
[submodule "third_party/bcrypt"]
        path = third_party/bcrypt
        url = https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt
```

So now, when I checkout my project and do a submodule update, it pulls down bcrypt to `${PROJ_ROOT}/third_party`

Next up, I added this to my ROOT CMakeLists.txt

```
# Process subdirectories
add_subdirectory(third_party/bcrypt) 
add_subdirectory(src/)
```

Great. I know see when I invoke cmake from root, it builds bcrypt inside third_party. And then it builds my src/ directory. The reason I do this is I assume this is the best way to make sure the bcrypt library is ready before my src directory is built.

Questions:

a) Now how do I correctly get the include header path and the library location of this built library into the CMakeLists.txt file inside `src/` ? Should I be hardcoding `#include "../third_party/bcrypt/include/bcrypt/bcrypt.h"` into `my_server.cpp` and  `-L ../third_party/libcrypt.so` into `src/CMakeLists.txt` or is there a better way? This is what I've done today and it works, but it looks odd

I have, in `src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(BCRYPT_LIB,"../third_party/bcrypt/libbcrypt.so")
target_link_libraries(my app ${MY_OTHERLIBS} ${BCRYPT_LIB})
```

b) Is my approach of relying on sequence of `add_directory` correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach depends on what the `bcrypt` CMake files are providing you, but it sounds like you want to use `find_package`, rather than hard-coding the paths. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857070/3987854) answer, but there are a few different configurations for `find_package`: `MODULE` and `CONFIG` mode.

If `bcrypt` builds, and one of the following files gets created for you:

```
FindBcrypt.cmake
bcrypt-config.cmake
BcryptConfig.cmake
```

that might give you an idea for which `find_package` configuration to use. I suggest you check out the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) for `find_package`, and look closely at how the search procedure is set up to determine how CMake is searching for `bcrypt`.