# How can I include a header-only library with CMake?

Tags: cmake

How can I add a header-only library outside the directory?

Previously I was using `add_subdirectory(HEADERLIBRARY)` only when the directory `HEADERLIBRARY` was inside the project directory. However, now I want to use the library for multiple projects, so I made a directory like this:

```
OUT
|----HEADERLIBRARY // of course contains CMakeLists.txt
|
|----project1
|----project2
|...
```

Is there a way to get the same effect as when I use `add_subdirectory`?

EDIT : HEADERLIBRARY = https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/doc/Installing-and-Using.md#add_subdirectory

Comment: If the header-only library exists outside of your source tree, you probably want the CMake `find_package` command. Here are the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).

Comment: I added
`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../HEADERLIBRARY)`
`find_package(headerlibrary)`
and still it doesn't work. What am I missing, or am I doing something wrong? @squareskittles

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857070/3987854) for some notes about how to use `find_package`. Depending on the setup of this header-only library, you'll want to approach `find_package` in one of two ways.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't get it. I have never used CMake in such a way(I only used it with CLion) and it seems that I should spend plenty of time for this. I added some info about `HEADERLIBRARY`. Would that help for me to get the answer? @squareskittles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you still just use `add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir] [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL])`.
Because `source_dir` is not within the source directory tree of the top-level project you have to specify the `[binary_dir]` folder that is going to be used.  By default `binary_dir` is the same as `source_dir` within the binary directory tree and it is handled automatically.