# CMake project in Visual Studio: How to add additional include and library directories?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, path

I am developing **C++** code using **VisualStudio** 2019.

I am using **CMake** to configure the project.

I need to use **boost** library which is compiled on my remote machine.

In **console application**, I can put the path of the include files I need when I go to the **Properties** of the project under **Additional Include Directories** field.
And under **Additional Include Directories** I can put the path of boost library.

Now I can not find **Properties** when I right-click on my project to add what I need.

My *boost include directory* is under */home/ubuntu/boost_1_70_0*

My *boost libraries directory* is under */home/ubuntu/boost_1_70_0/stage*

How can add them in my CMake project?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is my CMakelists.txt file:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject1, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h")


set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.70.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS lambda) 

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    add_executable(CMakeProject1 CMakeProject1.cpp) 
    target_link_libraries(CMakeProject1 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

And this is my .cpp file:

```
#include "CMakeProject1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::cout << "Type in any number: ";

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout
        << (boost::lambda::_1 * 10)
        << "\nType in another number: ");
}
```

The path of my boost directory is: */home/ubuntu/boost_1_70_0*

The path of my boost libraries is: */home/ubuntu/boost_1_70_0/stage*

When I run the .cpp file this CMake error occurs:

> Error     CMake Error at CMakeProject1/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package): 
>   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost"
>   (requested   version 1.70.0) with any of the following names:
>
> ```
> BoostConfig.cmake
> boost-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "Boost"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has been   installed.

Comment: [`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(path_to_include)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/include_directories.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add Boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: @squareskittles please can you see my problem edit

Comment: @ChrisMM is boostconfig.cmake and boost-config.cmake what I am missing here ? I must download them ?

Comment: I've never used boost; when you downloaded it, did it have those files? Do a search in the boost directory for them. If they already exist, then you just need to tell cmake where to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake's [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command has two modes: **Module** and **Config** mode. Many related questions on this site feature answers that are using **Module** mode. However, Boost 1.70 and greater provides a `BoostConfig.cmake` or `boost-config.cmake` package configuration file to easily use with `find_package()` **Config** mode. The package configuration file should be generated when you *build* Boost. For example, if you build Boost 1.72 into the `stage` directory, the `BoostConfig.cmake` file is located here:

```
boost_1_72_0/stage/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake
```

Your error indicates that you are using **Config** mode, so you have two options:

#### Option 1

Do the steps recommended in the error message to help the **Config** mode package search complete successfully. Append the path to your Boost installation to the prefix path by adding this line to your CMake file before `find_package()`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/ubuntu/boost_1_70_0)
```

#### Option 2

Force **Module** mode by setting the [`Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindBoost.html#boost-cmake) variable before the call to `find_package()`:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
```

Comment: Please can you describe me the difference between the two modes of `find_package` command ?

Comment: I added a link to the `find_package()` documentation in my post, which has lots of details. There are already questions about this topic on Stack Overflow, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857070/3987854) describes the differences between **Module** and **Config** mode pretty well.

Comment: Could you please see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60297265/11587528